# how to not sync pre filled data with icloud using CoreData and CloudKit

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

i use pre a filled SQLite file to have some default data in my app, and i want to modify, add an delete data.

so when i first run the app i copy my sqlite files from the app bundle to the app support directory so my container is pre filled with data that i can modify.

the problem is that if my container is sync with icloud all the pre filled data will be push to the cloud and i dont need it because those data are already on all my devices i just want to sync the modifications of those data

my first solution was to create a modifier for each data and sync with icloud only the modifier.
that work but is very complicate and not easy to maintain